# Transmitting JSON String from zmq (C) to Python problems

Tags: python, c, json, zeromq

I have a C program which generates a JSON string using the Jansson library.  The string is then sent over the ZMQ socket to a Python listener, which is trying to use the **json** library to decode the JSON string.  I am having trouble with the JSON decode because I think the quote symbols are getting messed up during the transmission.

In the C, I generate the following JSON Object:

> {"ticker":"GOOG"}

with the following code
`strcpy(jsonStrArr, "{\"ticker\":\"GOOG\"}\0");`

In python, I print out what I receive with the following code:
`print 'Received ' + repr(rxStr) +' on Queue_B'`

The printout that I'm seeing is:

> Received "{u'ticker': u'GOOG'}" on Queue_B

I'm not a JSON expert, but I think the **u'** is messing up the json.loads() function, because a double quote is required.

I know I need to so something to the **jsonStrArr** variable, but not sure what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the u is not messing up anything.

u'string' indicates that it's a unicode string.

Run this in python 2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = '؏' # It's just some arabic character I googled for, definitely not ascii
b = u'؏' 

print type(a)
>>> <type 'str'>
print type(b)
>>> <type 'unicode'>
```

So your json object is perfectly valid.

Note that the output of my example will be `<type 'str'>` for both string in python 3

Edit: Trying json.loads on the output you had in your post does indeed not work.

I found that printing the json code in python 2.7 changes {"ticker":"GOOG"} into {u'ticker': u'GOOG'}, however, that's just a representation, it's still valid json.

To properly print the json, you'll have to use the [json.dumps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) function. So replace repr(rxStr) with json.dumps(rxStr)

```
import json

a = json.loads(u'{"ticker": "GOOG"}')

print a
>>> "{u'ticker': u'GOOG'}"
print json.dumps(a)
>>> {"ticker": "GOOG"}
```

Once again, python 3 will behave differently on printing the string, since in python 3 string are automatically unicode strings if I recall correctly.

Comment: what you said works, so the line of code would be:
`rxStr = json.dumps(rx)` and then I'm able to access the dictionary with keys in unicode format, such as `rxDict[u'GOOG']`.  Seems a bit counterintuitive though, I already had a JSON string and I do `json.dumps` on it first, instead of `json.loads`?